# How pass arguments for ORDS RESTful services parameters?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I am new to ORDS RESTful services and data sources. I've seen videos talking about RESTful services but unfortunately, all of them talking about handling it using a tool like POSTMAN, so you can call the Endpoint URL and pass arguments when needed. But I need to know how call those Endpoint URL's using APEX. For example, I have created a Module, Template with URI template attribute set to `dept/:deptno` and a GET handler with query `select * from dept where deptno = :deptno or :deptno is null` Then I created a web source module using the previously mentioned Endpoint URL. And I was able to create an Interactive report based on that REST Data source. But there is no way to send an argument for the parameter `:deptno`. How do you pass arguments for parameters created through URI template attribute?

Comment: I think APEX has a helper package for making http calls, which might be easier than just using the htp generic database package

Comment: I believe there's no need to write code at all. Because auto-rest enabling a table and building a rest data source above it enables me to create a report and a form on that rest data source allows all database operations to be executed without any code at all. And I've seen a video for one doing the same. But no one demonstrates what happens in the background. And I need to understand that.

Comment: Deptno is likely passed via the uri, so just call /apex/dept/25 and 25 gets dynamically mapped to : deptno